# Display complex numbers as magnitude/angle by default in iPython

Tags: python

I love using iPython for my back-of-the-napkin math. Is it possible to make a switch function that changes the print behaviour of complex numbers such that it prints out magnitudes and angles vs real + imag*j?

Answer (score 0):

Use python's inbuilt library [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) for complex number operations:

```
import cmath

z = complex(3,4)

p = cmath.polar(z)  #Convert rectangular to polar coordinates
r = cmath.rect(*p)  #Convert polar to rectangular coordinates

print("Polar       :",p)
print("Rectangular :",r)
```

Output:

```
Polar       : (5.0, 0.9272952180016122)
Rectangular : (3.0000000000000004+3.9999999999999996j)
```

Comment: I was thinking of hacking the __repr__ method of the complex type.. maybe that's not a good idea.